# How to repair 'net start task scheduler' is invalid?

Tags: windows

I am using Windows Task Scheduler to automate my R script to convert PDF to Excel and it does not work.

I realize this `net start task scheduler` has some problem after since it's invalid but I do not know how to fix it.

What should I do if my `net start task scheduler` is invalid while my `net start lanmanserver` has already been started?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start task scheduler The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start lanmanserver The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.
```

Answer (score 0):

The name for the Task Scheduler service should just be 'schedule' but I also seem to recall that not even Administrator has permission to start/stop the service since it's meant to always be running. You might be able to get around that by running a shell as the service account (using psexec or similar) but I'm not entirely sure why you'd need to start the service at all as it should already be running.

Your problem starting LanmanServer is simply due to the service already being started.

Answer (score 0):

I do think my task scheduler is spoilt or something coz its an 6-7yr old laptop and ive checked the history logs of my laptop's task scheduler and it register nothing meaning to say my laptop's task scheduler is spoilt from day 1. I'm quite a noob in this.

Anywayz, I've already downloaded another scheduler and it's running fine now.
Anyone with the task scheduler issue as i have or maybe some other issues can simply download those free scheduler from the website such as 'System Scheduler' to resolve the problem.